# Tipsi-Stripe: Failing to create source from token

Tags: javascript, react-native, stripe-payments

Absolutely no clue what could be the problem here, and I don't know what this error means. When trying to create a source from my token, i'm getting this error:

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 40):

Error: The payment method `card` requires the parameter: card[number].
Error: The payment method `card` requires the parameter: card[number].
    at Object.promiseMethodWrapper [as createSourceWithParams] (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2275:36)
    at Stripe.createSourceWithParams (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:190106:29)
    at payWithCard$ (http://localhost:8081/src/CheckoutForm.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=true&runModule=false&shallow=true:383:72)
    at tryCatch (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:28564:19)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:28740:24)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:28607:23)
    at tryCatch (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:28564:19)
    at invoke (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:28640:22)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:28650:15
    at tryCallOne (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:3475:14)
```

Here is my code. I've tried every combination of anything, but i'm not sure what card[number] means. My token is definitely valid, and I am passing the correct value in per the docs: https://tipsi.github.io/tipsi-stripe/docs/createsourcewithparamsparams.html

```
 const options = {
      requiredBillingAddressFields: 'full',
      theme: {
        primaryBackgroundColor: '#f1f1f1',
      },
    };

    const token = await stripe.paymentRequestWithCardForm(options);
    const params = {
      type: 'card',
      amount: 50,
      // currency: 'USD',
      // returnURL: 'example://stripe-redirect',
      card: token.card.cardId,
      // card: token.card,
      // card123: token.card.cardId,
      token: token.tokenId,
    };

    console.log(token);
    const source = await stripe.createSourceWithParams(params);
    alert(source);
    console.log(source);
```

Any suggestions would be verymuch appreciated. This is a big library, I would think this issue is widespread? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The API has changed and the docs aren't updated. This is the new format:

```
 const source = await stripe.createSourceWithParams({
    type: 'card',
    number: '5555555555554444',
    expMonth: 11,
    expYear: 29,
    cvc: '789',
  })
```